# Updating and returning a list of Strings

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to make a simple program in Haskell that generates guitar tabs from a user-inputted list of chords. I'm new to Haskell and am having a hard time figuring out some of the basics of lists of Strings.

Tab are of the form:

```
--1----3--

--1----5--

--1----5--

--3----5--

--3----3--

--1----3--
```

I start with a list of empty Strings that I declare and then add chords to one at a time, in the following form:

```
[[line1],

 [line2],

 [line3],

 [line4],

 [line5],

 [line6]]
```

and each time I add a new chord to the tab I'm building, I need to cons the appropriate String for that chord onto each of my six lines

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
addG :: [String] -> [String]
addG (a:b:c:d:e:f) = [[a++gOne],[b++gTwo],[c++gThree],[d++gFour],[e++gFive],[f++gSix]]
```

where:

```
gOne :: String
gOne = "---3---"

gTwo :: String
gTwo = "---3---"
```

etc

With this particular syntax, I get the following error in ghci:

```
project.hs:40:24: error:
    Couldn't match expected type 'Char' with actual type '[Char]'
    In the expression: a ++ gOne
    In the expression: [a ++ gOne]
    In the expression: 
        [[a ++ gOne], [b ++ gTwo], [c ++ gThree], [d ++ gFour], ....]
```

I get the exact same error five more times for each of the other Strings b-f.

Comment: @Carcigenicate thank you for the edits, sorry about that

Comment: Np. Just please make sure for future questions that you take care to format your code before posting. Questions are received better when they're readable. And what errors are you getting? Please edit them into the question.

Comment: I would make the tab a list of chords (a list of six element lists), and then `Data.List.transpose` at the end.

Comment: @luqui oh wow I didn't even know that existed. I looked it up and that sounds like exactly what I need. thank you so much